# DRY Devise models that need to send emails asynchronously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, dry

I have multiple Devise models in my app (User, Admin, etc). I can successfully send Devise notification emails asynchronously by overriding #send_devise_notification in each of the models.

```
# user.rb, admin.rb, etc

private
##
# Uses Active::Job to send Devise's emails asynchronously.
##
def send_devise_notification(notification, *args)
  devise_mailer.send(notification, self, *args).deliver_later
end
```

Since this code is exactly the same in all of the models, I figured I could make a Concern called DeviseAsyncCapable which implements #send_devise_notification the same way as I describe above.

```
# devise_async_capable.rb
module DeviseAsyncCapable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def send_devise_notification(notification, *args)
    devise_mailer.send(notification, self, *args).deliver_later
  end
end

# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include DeviseAsyncCapable
end
```

After including the concern in one of the models and testing it, the method defined in the concern was not called, instead Devise sent emails inline. How can I DRY this code?

Comment: Include DeviseAsyncCapable after `devise :database_autheticable`

Answer (score 0):

**Update - Answer**

As bcd replied, you need to include the concern after you call devise :database_autheticable

```
#user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable#, ...

  include DeviseAsyncCapable
end
```